# how can we clear whatsapp conversations in our contacts

Tags: applications, updates, backup

I have a doubt on whatsapp msgs.my frd msg me on whatsapp I seen the whole coversation.on the next day I didn't find any conversation in my phone.I face this situation from couple of my frds.Is it possible to delete the conversations from other cells reply me quickly.

Comment: We have a lot of visitors whose first language isn't English. To help most people understand your posts, please use full words, not "txtspeak" abbreviations.

Answer (score 3):

The [WhatsApp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/bb/23704633) has instructions that should help you:

> **To delete a single message from a conversation:**
>
> Open WhatsApp and go to the chat window with the message you want to
>   delete. Highlight the message. Press the 'del' key on your keyboard.
>
> **To delete an individual or group chat:**
>
> In the  Chats screen, highlight the chat you wish to delete. Press the
>   button and select Delete chat or Delete and Exit Group.
>
> **To delete your entire chat history and remove yourself from all groups:**
>
> Go to WhatsApp >  Settings. Scroll to the bottom and select  Advanced
>   Settings. Press the  button and select Delete Chat History.
>
> **NOTE:** Using Delete Chat History will delete all chats from the Chats screen, as well as remove yourself from all groups.
>
> **To delete all messages in a conversation without closing the chat window or leaving the group**
>
> Open the chat. Press the  button and select Clear conversation.
>
> **To clear all chat history, but continue to participate in groups:**
>
> Go to WhatsApp >  Settings. Scroll to the bottom and select  Advanced
>   Settings. Press the  button and select Clear All Chats.
>
> **NOTE:** Using Clear All Chats will not remove you from any groups.

Comment: If you find information elsewhere, you must cite your source and give proper credit to the original authors. Please do so in the future.